# Neural network doesn't converge - using Multilayer Perceptron

Tags: neural-network

I've developed a "Pong" style game which effectively has a ball at the bottom of the screen and bouncy walls on the left and right and a sticky wall on the top. It randomly chooses a point on the bottom (on a straight horizontal line) and a random angle, bounces off the side walls, and hits the top wall. This is repeated a 1000 times and each time, the x-value of the launch position, the launch angle and the final x-value of the position it collides with on the top wall.

This gives me 2 inputs - x-value of launch and launch angle and 1 output - x-value of final position. I tried using a multilayer perceptron with 2 input nodes, 2 hidden nodes (1 layer) and 1 output node. However it converges upto a point ~20 and then tapers off. Here's what I've tried and none of them helped, either the error never converges or it starts diverging:

1. Transform inputs and output to be between 0 and 1
2. Transform inputs and output to be between -1 and 1
3. Increase number of hidden layers
4. Increase number of nodes in hidden layer
5. Convert the launch position, launch angle and final position into 0s and 1s resulting in ~750+175 inputs and ~750 outputs - no convergence

So, after spending all night and morning and making my brain and body revolt against me, I'm hoping someone can help me identify the problem here. Is this a task that's just not solvable by a neural network or am I doing something wrong?

PS: I'm using the online version of [Neuroph](http://neuroph.sourceforge.net/online_demo.html) and not coding my own procedure. At least this will help me avoid issues in implementation

Answer (score 3):

If it doesn't minimize the training error, that's most likely a bug in the implementation. If you're measuring the accuracy on a held-out test set, on the other hand, there's nothing surprising about the error going up after a while.

As to the formulation, I think *with sufficient amount of training data and sufficiently long training time, a sufficiently complex NN can learn the mapping* whether you binarize the input or not (provided the implementation you use supports non-binary input and output). I have only a vague idea of what "sufficient" means in the above sentence, but I'd venture a guess that 1000 samples won't do. Note also that the more complex the network, the more data it will generally need to estimate the parameters.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The error is reducing, but the rate of decrease is reducing. So it will not go below a certain number which is ~14-20. I also don't want to overfit the data to work very well with the training set and be terrible with any new data. I've tried increasing the number of params to include the bounces on each of the walls, but the error has only reduced by a small amount.

But I think you have something with the number of samples. I'll see if I can get a bigger training set of maybe 10,000 and see if that helps.

Comment: The error is the training error. It effectively tells you how well your training data fits with the calculated parameters of the neural network. For example, for my training set X, I'm using the backpropagation algorithm to generate the parameters to fit the data. If the training error is high (>2) it's not a very good fit. If it's low (<0.5) that means it's a reasonably good fit and it is "more likely" to do well with predicting the output accurately of any new input that we provide it with. In any case, neuroph does this for you without having to write any code.

Comment: @PlastyGrove I'm well aware of what training error is, but there's more than one way to measure the performance of a multi-class classifier. I gather you use just the proportion of the samples classified incorrectly?

Comment: Ah, sorry about that. I'm not sure how the error is estimated. As I said, Neuroph gives me a nice gui to use and displays the error value with iterations. I'm guessing the error is calculated using the entire training set and how "far" the prediction is from the actual value for each example.

Answer (score 1):

To eliminate potential implementation issues in Neuroph, I'd suggest trying the exact same process (Multi-Layer Perceptron, same parameters, same data, etc.) but use [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) instead.

I've used the MLP in Weka before with success, so I can verify that this implementation works correctly.  I know Weka has a fairly high-penetration in the academic community and its fairly well vetted, but I'm not sure about Neuroph since its newer.  If you get the same results as Neuroph, then you know the issue is in your data or neural net topology or configuration.

Qnan brings up a good point - what exactly is the error you are measuring?  To really determine why the training error isn't converging towards zero, you need to determine what exactly it is that the error represents.

Also, how many epochs (i.e., number of iterations) is the neural net running in training before it stops converging?

In Weka, if I recall correctly you can set the training to execute either until the error reaches a certain value or for a certain number of epochs.  Looks like Neuroph is the same way, from a quick look.

If you're limiting the number of epochs, try bumping up the number to something significantly higher to give the network more iterations to converge.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I think that's a good suggestion. So far, I've been assuming 1000 samples was decent enough. I'll try increasing that number and also give Weka a shot. Thanks!

Comment: @PlastyGrove - Did you ever find an answer to your question?  Just curious.

Comment: Apologies for the late reply, but I struggled a fair amount with this and then just gave up. I felt the issue was that my understanding of neural networks was too basic and further reading was necessary. But at the moment, it's pretty much abandoned